# Only activate observable if another observable has emitted

Tags: rxjs

Here's the scenario: there are two observable streams (`A` and `B`). I want to only emit from `B` after `A` has emitted at least once.

I tried `combineLatest`, but the problem with that was that the combined stream emitted when either `A` or `B` emitted. I only want this stream to emit when `B` emits, I do not need the value from `A`. I just need it to have been emitted once.

This is what I am looking for:

```
---a---a-- A
-b---b---- B
---b-b---- required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```js
combineLatest(a$.pipe(first()), b$)
  .pipe(
    map(([a, b]) => b)
  )
```

`combineLatest` will emit for the first time when both `a$` and `b$` would have emitted, then it will only emit when `b$` emits, due to `a$.pipe(first())`.

Answer (score 0):

Once the combine latest emits then switch back to b.

```
combineLatest(a$, b$).pipe(
  map(([a, b]) => b),
  switchMap(_ => b$)
);
```